# Can someone help me make a cross-browser drop down navigation bar?

Tags: css

I'm working on my tumblr theme. I was wondering if someone could help me create a very simple drop down navigation bar that works in all browsers, with as little CSS as possible.

Comment: First result googling for "dropdown navigation": http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pure CSS solution that I know of.  However, this would work if you like to get your hands dirty:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menu {
display: none;
}
</style>
<title>HI</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="out" style="background-color: blue; width:100px; height: 50px; user-select:  none;-webkit-user-select:none">
Rollover me!
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>Menu</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(event) {
drop = document.getElementById('menu');
drop.style.cssText = 'display: block';
}
function hide(event) {
drop = document.getElementById('menu');
drop.style.cssText = 'display: none';
}

menu = document.getElementById("out");
menu.addEventListener("mouseover", show, false);
menu.addEventListener("mouseout", hide, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure how much Javascript tumblr allows though.

Answer (score 2):

@IslandCow:
Of course there is a css only solution:

Check [this out](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/6nYC5/):

```
<div id="nav">
    <div>Main Nav</div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub nav 1</a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub nav 2</a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub nav 3</a></div>
</div>

<style>
    #nav{
        background-color:#8be;
        width:120px;
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #nav:hover{
        height:80px;
    }
</style>
```

[Version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/6nYC5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Read the ancient-but-still-relevant [Suckerfish Dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/) article on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

This is where I first learned Pure CSS menus with Javascript enhancements for browsers that didn't to the CSS correctly.